# Why i can't open second stream in java?

Tags: java, stream

Here is my problem.I've made simple input class with methods for getting primitive values from user's keyboard.The problem is that whenever i use this class in my other classes i face the problem that when i made more than one instance of this class i get a problem of the "Close stream".Why is this happening?

For example:i have a main method where i get user's input and decide which object to make,say i can make 4 different objects(4 classes),after i call the objects "set state" method,where i actually set all the states of this object with making second instance of the input class,and then ,when i try to read again the user's input in my main method,i get an exception "Stream closed".
Here is the code of the input class :

```
public class UserInput {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));;

  public int getInt() {
    try {
      String line;
      line = reader.readLine();
      return Integer.parseInt(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public double getDouble() {
    try {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      return Double.parseDouble(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public float getFloat() {
    try {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      return Float.parseFloat(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public long getLong() {
    try {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      return Long.parseLong(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public short getShort() {
    try {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      return Short.parseShort(line);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public String getString() {
    try {
      String line = reader.readLine();
      return line;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return " ";
    }
  }

  public char getChar() {
    try {
      return (char) reader.read();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return (' ');
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    if (reader != null) {
      try {
        reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "Why is this happening?" You don't show the code using this class, but I'd imagine it's because you're calling the `close()` method. The general rule of thumb is not to close a stream you didn't open; and you didn't open `System.in`.

Comment: The reader you close closes the underlying stream, in your case `System.in`. Once that's closed, you can't reopen it.

Comment: Thank you very much,now i understand.Is there any possible way to close the BufferedReader without closing the System.in ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way for user input is to use a `Scanner` which already contains methods for reading different kinds of input.

You're not supposed to close the `reader`, because that will then close `System.in` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `reader.close();` you are not only closing the reader himself because the call invokes the `close()` method of the `InputStreamReader` aswell and therefore closes `System.in` (which you can not reopen).

A possible Solution would be to use a `Scanner` as Kayaman pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748625/8181750) or to override the `close()` method like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in){@Override public void close(){});
```

Comment: There's no need to override `close()`. Just don't call `close()` and everything's fine.